# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while trying to use pysndfx

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, subprocess, filepath

I'm trying to sound process a wav file with python and pysndfx but getting this weird error. I've tried many different path formats and many different paths. Even thought os.path.isfile() returns true it still comes up with this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from pysndfx import AudioEffectsChain
import os

in_file = os.getcwd() + "\\" + "a.mp3"
in_file = in_file.replace("\\", "//")#tried many things here, tried to it without any replacing

if os.path.isfile(in_file):
    print("fileyes") #This returns true
else:
    print("not a file")
print(in_file)


fs = 44100
fx = (AudioEffectsChain().
    reverb().
    delay().
    phaser()
)

fx(in_file,"apro.mp3")
```

Here's the error

```
fileyes
E://PyEarTraning//Test//a.mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/PyEarTraning/Test/test.py", line 28, in <module>
    fx(in_file,"E:\\PyEarTraning\\Test\\apro.mp3")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pysndfx\dsp.py", line 368, in __call__
    infile = FilePathInput(src)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pysndfx\sndfiles.py", line 29, in __init__
    stdout, stderr = Popen(shlex.split(info_cmd, posix=False),
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment (yet) so i'll ask here. Do you have your file in the same directory (folder) as the python program? If not then it won't work even if the file does actually exist somewhere. Try to copy or move both your file and program code into a new/the same folder.

Comment: It IS in the same folder

Comment: Then try naming your file with .(filetype). So if I was trying to open a txt file it would be fgvjdk = open("file.txt")